# Font awesome with wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, css, wordpress, font-awesome

I'm trying to take this code from a html site and put it into my theme via the `wp_nav_menu` function:

```
<div class="bottom">
<!-- Social Icons -->
    <ul class="icons">
        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-github"><span class="label">Github</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-dribbble"><span class="label">Dribbble</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-envelope"><span class="label">Email</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

So far I have the written text displaying in the right place but I'm unable to get the classes to display the actual icon instead of text. I would like it to look exactly as the code that is pasted above. Here is the current function I'm using.

```
<div class="bottom">
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'social-media' ) ) {

    wp_nav_menu(
        array(
            'theme_location'  => 'social-media',
            'container'       => 'false',
            'container_id'    => '',
            'container_class' => '',
            'menu_class'      => 'icons',
            'depth'           => 1,
            'fallback_cb'     => '',
        )
    );
} 
?>
</div>
```

I greatly appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Did you added the font-awsome css into your page?

Comment: @Vishal Yes, font-awesome is already in my theme and working. I can even assign the font awesome class through the menu section in the css class field when creating a custom link and they will display next to any text I put in the text field. What I want to do is hard code the label and hardcode class into my wp_nav_menu so that when I create a custom link it displays exactly like the html version. The issue I'm having is that I cannot find a way to add all of the classes to the wp_nav_menu function.